# Android FTP server authenticates once

Tags: android, ftp, ftp-server

I am trying to implement an FTP server in my application using the `Apache FTP server library`.

The server is up and running and working fine, but only once.

Note: I am using a hardcoded user for now. `username: test` and `password: test`

So in order:

1. App is launched, server is started, lets all FTP clients login.
2. App is killed by user.
3. App is started by user and server is started. Replies `530 authentication failed` to user logging in with `username: test` and `password: test`

After that it responds with `530 authentication failed`

My code below for making the server:

```
public void makePropertiesFile(){
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/user.properties");
    if(file.exists() == false){
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            logMessage("user.properties File did not exist, made one");
            properties = file;
            this.addUsers();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        logMessage("File already exists, no need to recreate");
        userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
        userManagerFactory.setFile(properties);
        userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
        org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
        serverFactory.setUserManager(userManager);
    }
}

public void addUsers(){
    userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
    userManagerFactory.setFile(properties);
    userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
    baseUser = new BaseUser();
    baseUser.setName("test");
    baseUser.setPassword("test");
    baseUser.setHomeDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    baseUser.setEnabled(true);
    List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<Authority>();
    authorities.add(new WritePermission());
    baseUser.setAuthorities(authorities);
    org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
    try {
        userManager.save(baseUser);
    } catch (FtpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logMessage("Could not save User");
    }
    serverFactory.setUserManager(userManager);
}

public void start(){
    serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
    listenerFactory = new ListenerFactory();
    listenerFactory.setPort(port);
    serverFactory.addListener("default",listenerFactory.createListener());
    ftpServer = serverFactory.createServer();
    this.makePropertiesFile();
    try {
        ftpServer.start();
        logMessage("Started FTP server on port: " + port);
    } catch (FtpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logMessage("Failed to start FTP server on port: " + port);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this link http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120

has a working project FTP with Android app